# Binding grid with static data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written Gridview code like below lines of codes

```
                                                 <div  class="overflowX">
                        <asp:GridView ID="grdView" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderWidth="0" runat="server" CssClass="table">
                            <Columns>

                              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Non-Resident License">
                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:Label ID="lblJurisdiction" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />
                                   </ItemTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>


              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Effective Date">
                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEffectiveDate" style="padding:12px 5px;" placeholder="(mm/dd/yyyy)" CssClass="datepiker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>
                              </Columns>

                        </asp:GridView>

                                   </div>
```

In cs file

```
private void FillJurisdictionGrid(string Jurisdiction, string IssueDate)
{
    Jurisdiction = "Alabama, Alaska, Arizona";
    IssueDate = "12/10/2015";

    if (Jurisdiction != "")
    {
        grdView.Visible = true;
        grid.Visible = true;
        txtJurisdiction.Enabled = false;
        string[] jurisdictionData = Jurisdiction.Split(',');
        grdView.DataSource = jurisdictionData;
        grdView.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        grid.Visible = false;
        grdView.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

I want that Grid should look like

- Non-Resident License - Effective Date
- Alabama - 12/10/2015
- Alaska - 12/10/2015
- Arizona - 12/10/2015

I want that date should appear same in all rows in grid view's  txtEffective` date textbox.

Please help me.

Comment: You are passing parameters to `FillJurisdictionGrid` which immediately get modified. This looks strange to me.

Comment: Jurisdiction = "Alabama, Alaska, Arizona"; And  IssueDate = "12/10/2015"     are just to make question better understandable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string Jurisdiction = "Alabama, Alaska, Arizona";
        string IssueDate = "12/10/2015";
        FillJurisdictionGrid(Jurisdiction, IssueDate);
    }
    private void FillJurisdictionGrid(string Jurisdiction, string IssueDate)
    {


        if (Jurisdiction != "")
        {
            grdView.Visible = true;
            //grid.Visible = true;
            //txtJurisdiction.Enabled = false;
            string[] jurisdictionData = Jurisdiction.Split(',');
            grdView.DataSource = jurisdictionData;

            grdView.DataBind();

            for (int i = 0; i < grdView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox txtEffectiveDate = (TextBox)grdView.Rows[i].FindControl("txtEffectiveDate");
                txtEffectiveDate.Text = IssueDate;//By chance you want to pass the Textbox Value

            }

        }
        else
        {
            //  grid.Visible = false;
            grdView.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
` private void FillJurisdictionGrid()
    {
        string Jurisdiction = "Alabama, Alaska, Arizona";
        string IssueDate = "12/10/2015";

        if (Jurisdiction != "")
        {
            grdView.Visible = true;
            string[] jurisdictionData = Jurisdiction.Split(',');
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Jurisdiction");
            dt.Columns.Add("IssueDate");
            for (int i = 0; i < jurisdictionData.Length; i++)
            {
                DataRow toInsert = dt.NewRow();
                dt.Rows.InsertAt(toInsert, i);
                dt.Rows[i]["Jurisdiction"] = jurisdictionData[i].ToString();
                dt.Rows[i]["IssueDate"] = IssueDate;
            }
            grdView.DataSource = jurisdictionData;
            grdView.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            grdView.Visible = false;
        }
    }`
```